# Replace HTML contents strings to normal text in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How to replace `&quot;` `&gt;` `&amp;` from a column into Normal strings like `"` `<` `&` in postgresql

Comment: [replace](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.26.1.1.1)?

Comment: Postgres is the wrong place to do this. Use the HTML Decode function of your client's language to either decode the text before storing or before display. If you don't want the HTML-encoded text at all, don't store it in this form. If some applications want it and some don't, it's up to the applications to decode this